# Чувяк - подстилка для скота. (из тюрк.) Так ли это?

Tags: значение-слов

Чувяк - подстилка для скота. (из тюрк.) Так ли это? И как это связано с расхожим словом употребляемым молодёжью в просторечие: "Эй чувак!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этимология слова из молодежного сленга не установлена. 
Все имеющиеся в сети версии - не просто сомнительны, но неправдоподобны, если не очевидно подтасованы. Особенно разговоры про кастрированного барана (или ещё кого) - подобного слова в тюркских нет. 
Про подстилку не слышал, но думаю, что тоже ложно. 
Остальное - у Надюшки.

Чего ж меня-то приняли?
Приоритет ответа по сути - у Надюшки.

Comment: Извините. :-( Еще не совсем разобрался в ваших правилах. Но почти все свои очки отдал ей. Впрочем, я поставил не совсем корректный вопрос. Меня больше интересовала этимология сленга и его возможная связь со словом "чувяки." 
P.S. А что, принимать ответ и награждать за ответ нужно одно лицо?

Comment: Да, ответ принимается один раз у одного из ответивших. 
Дело не в очках. Думаю, Надюшка того же мнения.
Просто читающий должен видеть, какой ответ принят "как правильный"

Comment: Все в порядке)) Я тоже еще не до конца разобралась в опциях. Спасибо за баллы. Но свои старайтесь особо не раздавать. Больше баллов - больше возможностей на сайте (кажется, так)

Answer (score 4):

В словаре Ефремовой дается 2 значения этого слова: Чувя́ки 
 1. Кожаная обувь с мягкой подошвой (обычно у жителей Кавказа и Крыма).
 2. Мягкие туфли без каблуков.

В других словарях похожие определения. К "чуваку" никакого отношения не имеют.
  Самая подробная статья в Терминологическом словаре Л.В.Орленко http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/701452 (она же в Википедии)

Еще есть "чувяк" - в Иврито-русском словаре, значение - низкопоклонник, подхалим, шлёпанец. (Написание не могу скопировать). Но думаю, что это мало отношения имеет к "чуваку", т.к. значение другое.

В том же словаре Ефремовой "чувак" - Мужчина, молодой человек (разг.сниж.)

Comment: >Еще есть "чувяк" - в Иврито-русском словаре, значение - низкопоклонник, подхалим, шлёпанец. (Написание не могу скопировать). Но думаю, что это мало отношения имеет к "чуваку", т.к. значение другое.   
  
Как бы это вообще не заимствование из русского. Больно уж непохоже на исконное ивритское слово.

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы. Только про "чувака" не понял. Как и на основании чего, Ефремова, в своём словаре, связывает мужчину и "чувака"? Просто на основании факта "уличного" сленга? То же мне "научный труд"!

Comment: >Как и на основании чего, Ефремова, в своём словаре, связывает мужчину и "чувака"?  
  
На основании современного значения. Вы же не назовете чуваком женщину?

Comment: Я и мужчину "чуваком" не назову. Для меня этот оборот речи неприемлем.

Comment: В таком случае как Вы хотите разобраться в значении?

Comment: Я лишь хотел узнать почему мужчину называют "чуваком". И услышал всё, что Вы смогли мне ответить. Не всё, что ожидал, но, тем не менее, спасибо. Вопрос закрыт. 
   НО В ДАННЫЙ МОМЕНТ меня больше беспокоит один из ваших участников форума - "дерзкий". Он до сих пор пытается удалить вторую букву "Б" из слова суббота. Я его пытаюсь переубедить, но он ооочень решителен. :-)

Comment: Скажите, мне одному кажется, что Вы - очередной клон grumant'а?  
Должен сказать, что "бой с тенью" - занятие довольно интересное, но Вы перегибаете палку. Темы хотя бы не путайте.

Comment: Скажите, мне одному кажется, что Вы - очередной клон grumant'а?
   Вот я, по вашему, что сейчас должен делать? Есть землю? Прислать Вам копию паспорта. Заручится поддержкой рекомендательных писем? :-) Я не знаю grumant'а, клонов не создаю - мне это не нужно. Я в этой жизни себе уже всё доказал. А здесь я исключительно ради интересного и плодотворного общения. Я, по образованию, инженер - энергетик и мне приятно общаться не просто с образованными, но и умными людьми. К сожалению сейчас таких всё меньше и меньше. Уверяю Вас, Ваши подозрения безосновательны.